# Does yarn (Node.js package manager) provide cryptographic authentication and integrity validation?

Tags: authentication, integrity, node.js, package-manager, yarn

Does the `yarn` package manager cryptographically validate its payload's authentication and integrity for all packages after downloading them and before installing them?

I see a lot of guides providing installation instructions with steps asking the user to install Node.js dependencies with `yarn add ...`. I usually don't do this as I trust my OS package manager (ie `apt`) to actually validate the origin/trust and integrity of the package before installing it.

Does `yarn` provide cryptographic authentication and integrity checks for all items downloaded before installing them by default?

> Note: Transport validation via X.509 does not count as a valid auth/integrity check.

Comment: Yarn's documentation on the release process includes a step for gpg signing the tarball before publishing it https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/org/release-process/#toc-creating-a-new-release

Comment: See [this github issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1169) for related discussion.